# Pass package.json commands from a js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, node-addon-api, cmake-js

I am working on a node.js native addon. While building for 32bit and 64 bit I have to set two different command for two different field.

for **32bit**

```
"scripts": {
  "install": "cmake-js compile cmake -G \"Visual Studio 16 2019\" -A Win32"
},
"cmake-js": {
  "arch": "ia32"
},
```

---

for **64bit**

```
"scripts": {
  "install": "cmake-js compile cmake -G \"Visual Studio 16 2019\" -A x64"
},
"cmake-js": {
  "arch": "x64"
},
```

How can I set both **cmake-js** field and **install** field appropriately with a single command or Is their any way we can pass these command from java-script file.

I want something like
**npm run install32bit / install64bit**